# How to display time with momentjs in react

Tags: reactjs

I am running [React Datepicker](https://reactdatepicker.com/) and I'm getting the dates correctly, but the times are eluding me.

In the constructor I set the time like this

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            startdate: moment('20180702', 'YYYYMMDD'),
            starttime: moment('1122', 'HHmm'),
        };
    }
}
```

Later in my component render I have (parameters are explained in the React DatePicker docs). This is not really of importance for my problem but I'm sharing it anyway. My problem is mostly on that moment instatiation in my constructor:

```
<DatePicker
    customInput={<StartTime />}
    popperClassName={classes.datepickerCalendar}
    isClearable
    selected={this.state.starttime}
    onChange={this.handleStartTimeChange}
    showTimeSelect
    showTimeSelectOnly
    timeIntervals={15}
    timeFormat="HH:mm"
    timeCaption="Time"
/>
```

The date is giving me an output of `07/020/2018` but the time is giving me some random or odd date as well, not an actual time. More specifically `11:22`

I'm positive I am instatiating time incorrectly but I can't find an example in momentjs documentation.

How can I tell moment to display a time (i.e. 11:22)?

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that moment.js is a **date** library, so by doing `moment('1122', 'HHmm')` you are creating a new **date**, not an arbitrary "time". Since you don't specify day, month or year (on that particular line), moment assumes todays date. So this line will yeild the date: `2018/05/15 11:22`.

So, if you want to pass the date `2018/07/02 11:22`, you should do:

```
startdate: moment('20180702 1122', 'YYYYMMDD HHmm')
```

If your time seems off by a few hours, it's probably because the time will by default be printed in Zulu time (i.e GMT) which may not match your own timezone.

---

Demo:

```js
var now =  moment('20180702 1122', 'YYYYMMDD HHmm');
console.log(now);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.2.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can the date be excluded? I need to pass the date and time in different places. I got the date part down